# Error of fields required from Swagger in .NET core API built with EF core

Tags: .net, api, entity-framework-core, swagger, crud

I am a beginner in .NET core. I have two entities, entity Tech and entity Skill. Each Tech has a list of Skills, and Skill has the foreign key of Tech. The database is built with EF core.

The entities are like this:

Tech.cs

```cs
public class Tech
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TechName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; } = new List<Skill>();
    // for soft delete
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Skill.cs

```cs
public class Skill
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    // Foreign Key
    [Required]
    public int TechId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TechId")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Tech tech { get; set; }
    // For soft delete

    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

For skill

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Skill> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Skill");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    builder.Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    builder.Property(x => x.SkillName).HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)");
    builder.HasQueryFilter(b => !b.isDeleted);
    builder
        .HasOne(e => e.tech)
        .WithMany(e => e.Skills).HasForeignKey(e => e.TechId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); ;

    ICollection<Skill> skill_1 = new List<Skill>();
    skill_1 = AddDotNetSkill();

    builder.HasData(skill_1);
}
```

For Tech

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Tech> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Tech");
    builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    builder.Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    builder.Property(x => x.TechName).HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)");
    builder.HasQueryFilter(b => !b.isDeleted);



    Tech tech_1 = AddTechDotNet();
    Tech tech_2 = AddTechDatabases();

    builder.HasData(tech_1);
    builder.HasData(tech_2);
}
```

So I tried to create a CRUD api with the two entities. The get method is fine, but just when I try to do a HttpPost, Swagger will immediately reply with a 400 error without going into my controller.

```json
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-0c523d52d0f3f06ce2a64fe8fe59520a-974d7fc666a3a246-00",
  "errors": {
    "Skills[0].tech": [
      "The tech field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

The following is my controller

```cs
// POST: api/Techs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Tech> PostTech([FromBody] Tech tech)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Techs.Add(tech);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var skill in tech.Skills)
    {
        skill.TechId = tech.Id;
        _context.Add(skill);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Ok(tech);
}
```

I think the issue is with my foreign key of Tech tech, it would be really grateful if I could receive any suggestion related to this, thanks!

Comment: First of all you don't need to configuring anything in the FluentApi for that tables. EF Core can manage  that relation self.

Comment: What is the post data you send to PostTech ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. May I know by not needing to configure in FluentApi, does it mean that I don't need to specify their relationship?

for my post data its like this:

{
  "id": 3,
  "techName": "Java",
  "skills": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "skillName": "Java",
      "techId": 3,
      "isDeleted": false
    }
  ],
  "isDeleted": false
}

Comment: I have made the Tech in my Skill.cs as nullable, it seemed to work but I am not sure if that was a correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

By configuring the models like this, EF Core create relation between them "one to many" . No need explicitly point the relation in the FluentApi (only for one to one need)

```
public class Tech
{
    //Best way to initialize the collection directly in the model
    public Tech()
    {
        this.Skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] //nvarchar(50)
    public string TechName { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    
    // Relation to Skills 
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; };
}

public class Skill
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] //nvarchar(50)
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }

    //Relation to Tech
    public int TechId { get; set; }
    public Tech Tech { get; set; }
    
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Tech), 200)] //Specifind in the swagger the object your method receive
public async Task<ActionResult<Tech>> PostTech([FromBody] Tech tech)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    
    //Here you add the Tech in Techs table and all skills in the Skills table, no need separate save for skills
    await _context.AddAsync(tech);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(tech);
}
```

The Error 400 you get mean that your json data can't be deserialized to Tech object. I see in the object you send to the `PostTech` you pass `"id": 3`and `"techId": 3` in the `Slill` , but if you use code first approach EF create Ids as identity that mean you have to leave `Id` null same for skills

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me! May I know whats the difference between initializing in the model compared to the original way? I edited the code, it still wouldn't work unless I declare Tech tech in Skill.cs as nullable. Is it a normal practice?

Comment: if you make the initialization in the model you make two things firs never have null reference exception for that collection and second convert it to fastest collection "HashSet" you can